# Clear all selected items in a gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist, expandablelistview

I have a gridview inside a ExpandableListView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, I'm trying to deselect all items when I press a button, but the way I'm doing it it is only unselecting the last item, how can I clear all of them?

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return child.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isChecked = child.get(position).isChecked();
                if (!isChecked) {
                    child.get(position).setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    child.get(position).setChecked(false);                       
                }

                ex.findViewById(R.id.notificar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        //clear all selected items
                        for(int i = 0; i< getCount(); i++){
                            child.get(i).setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.text.setText(child.get(position).getNome());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}
```

Comment: You are doing it from the `adapter`, imo a better way would be to do this from the `activity/fragment` where the list exists. I have a similar situation for a listView and it works well. Just call a function in the activity/fragment on item's `onClick` and run the deselection loop there.

Comment: While I try to help you, would you please change the first 6 lines of your `onClick` handler function to `child.get(position).setChecked(!isChecked)`? It's dificult to focus on the question with those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `listView.clearChoices();` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the activity or fragment containing the list, not inside the adapter.

Comment: What about calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the `listView.clearChoices()`? Another option woule be the `listView.setSelected()` method.

Comment: I was just missing the notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using calling `child.size` first, it is returning 1.
You are getting the child count from a different view.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return child.size();
}
```

If you call `child.size()` within   you `OnClickListener` where you are using the

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
```

You should be iterating through the array adapter of the list, as the child.counts of the view will be different from the number of checked list items, if the list is scrollable. As there will be less items in the view (they are recycled) than within the list.